# matplotlib colorbar update/remove destroys axes layout

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, colorbar

I have matplotlib embedded in a tkinter gui. With the seaborn heatmap function, I create a heatmap and a colorbar which works as I want it to when creating the first plot. However, if I plot again, this will not overwrite the colorbar but add another colorbar to my figure. I end up with to many colorbars this way.

The figure I create for the plot contains two axes:

```
[<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x000001F36C8C3390>, <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x000001F36D6ABF98>]
```

the first one is the plot itself and the second the colorbar and looks like this:
[plot 1](https://imgur.com/cQeIFb4.png)

If I plot again, the result is:
[plot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6Qoi.png)

Simply deleting the colorbar with

```
self.fig.axes[1].remove()
```

before creating the next plot doesn't do the trick because it will just remove the colorbar but the layout of the plot keeps shrinking:

[plot 3](https://imgur.com/cQeIFb4.png)
[plot 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCUtW.png)

Note that the figure size stays the same but the size of the plot keeps getting smaller when I plot again and the colorbar moves futher to the left while the entire right part of the plot stays white.

As I create a tkinter gui, the ploting window is initialized when the program is first run.

```
self.fig = plt.figure.Figure( facecolor = "white", figsize = (7,4)) 

          self.ax = self.fig.subplots()

          self.x_data = x_data
          self.y_data = y_data
```

when somebody presses a plot button the plot is created

```
    def plot_on_plotframe(self):
        self.ax.cla()

        #executes required matplotlib layout
        self.plotlayout[self.plot_type]()

        print('plottype: {}'.format(self.plot_type))       
        #print('Plot xdata: {}'.format(self.x_data))
        self.canvas.draw()
```

I need to make different types of plot and the proper type is selected by plotlayout:

```
        self.ax = sns.heatmap(self.x_data, vmin=self.settings[2][0], vmax=self.settings[2][1], cmap='viridis', fmt=self.settings[0], annot=self.settings[1], linewidths=0.5, annot_kws={'size': 8}, ax = self.ax)

        self.ax.set_xticklabels(self.ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=0)
        self.fig.tight_layout()
```

It would be fantastic if somebody could tell me why matplotlib messes with the layout even after I delete the old colorbar in the first place. I think this has something to do with the gridSpec but I don't get how I tell matplotlib to reset the layout properly. Also any other suggestions on how to resovle this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are just laying plot over plot this way.  I'd just remove both axes and start over at each step.  If you don't want to do that for efficiency reasons you'll have to get more low level than `sns.heatmap` and change the z-data for the pcolor.

Comment: matplotlib has to mess w/ the layout at each step because it needs to make room for the colorbar each time you add one.  you can probably reset the position based on the pre-colorbar position and re-call `heatmap`, but you'd probably in the end be better off just duplicating what heatmap does and doing the layout yourself.

Comment: If you want to rely on seaborn's heatmap, you may instead of clearing the axes, clear the entire figure. Also possible, predefine an axes for the heatmap and an axes for the colorbar. Then plot the `heatmap(..., ax=ax, cbar_ax=cbar_ax)` to those existing axes.

Comment: I tried clearing the entire figure each time a new plot is created with ```self.fig.clf()``` and ```self.fig.clear('all')``` but this doesn't help. The colorbar is moving to the left nontheless. ```self.fig.remove()``` raises an 'NotImplementedError'